# How to INSERT a record using _date in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is driving me insane. I'm trying to INSERT a value into the following "stats" table:

```
_date       spam1
-----------------
2011-06-13
```

using

```
INSERT INTO stats (spam1) VALUES (7) WHERE `_date` = '2011-06-13'
```

MySQL returns

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'WHERE `_date` = '2011-06-13'' at line 1
```

I don't understand. Removing the quotes around the date or the backticks around _date doesn't help either. What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]
Thanks - you all get an upvote :) How stupid of me...of course I need an UPDATE instead of INSERT...time to take a break I guess :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an UPDATE not an INSERT, try:

```
UPDATE stats SET `spam1` = 7  WHERE `_date` = '2011-06-13'
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should consider using UPDATE instead of INSERT

```
UPDATE stats SET spam1 = 7 WHERE _date = '2011-06-13';
```

Answer (score 2):

An `INSERT` statement lets you add a new record (a new row) to a table. You want to `UPDATE` an existing record:

```
UPDATE stats SET spam1 = 7 WHERE `_date` = '2011-06-13';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main forms for INSERT:

1. `INSERT INTO Table[(columns)] VALUES(...)`
2. `INSERT INTO Table[(columns)] SELECT ...`

You can use a WHERE clause as part of the SELECT version.

What are you trying to achieve?  An UPDATE, setting the `spam1` column value to 7 where the date is the given date?

```
UPDATE Stats SET Spam1 = 7 WHERE _Date = '2011-06-13';
```